# SQL select com where dinâmico no ABAP

Tags: sql, select, where, erp, abap

Existe a possibilidade de criar um select com where dinâmico na linguagem abap?

Comment: Será que te ajuda @Glauco? [How to use Dynamic SQL in ABAP](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/26881)

Answer (score 1):

Tem jeito sim segue o exemplo:

[image: print]

```
CONCATENATE sy-sysid '%' sy-mandt INTO DATA(logsys_aux).
CONCATENATE ' logsys like ''%' logsys_aux '%''' INTO DATA(logsys).
SELECT SINGLE logsys FROM tbdls INTO wa_mdfe_header-logsys WHERE (logsys).
```